# For $p\in(1,\infty)$, why does $||f||_p=||g||_p=\left|\left|\frac{f+g}{2}\right|\right|_p$ imply that $f=g$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

**Problem Statement.**

I am working on the following exercise:

> Prove that if $\mu$ is a measure, $p\in(1,\infty)$ and $f,g\in
>  L^p(\mu)$ are such that
>   $$||f||_p=||g||_p=\left|\left|\frac{f+g}{2}\right|\right|_p,$$ then
>   $f=g$.

---

**Notation.**

For a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $p\in(0,\infty]$ (where $\mathbf{F}$ is taken to be either $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$):

1. $L^p(\mu)=\{\tilde{f}: f\in\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)\}$
2. $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)=\{f:X\rightarrow\mathbf{F}: f \text{ is } \mathcal{S}\text{-measurable and } \int f\,d\mu<\infty\}$
3. $\tilde{f}=\{f+z: z\in\mathcal{Z}(\mu)\}$ where $\mathcal{Z}(\mu)$ is the set of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbf{F}$ that equal $0$ almost everywhere.

---

**My Thoughts.**

I am a bit confused as to how this is even an exercise, and here is why.  We define $$||\tilde{f}||_p=||f||_p$$ for $p\in (0,\infty].$  Thus even though the $f$ and $g$ given are actually $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$, it doesn't matter since $||\tilde{f}||_p=||f||_p$ and $||\tilde{g}||_p=||g||_p$, thus implying that $||f||_p=||g||_p$.  But if this is the case then $$\left(\int |f|^p\,d\mu \right)^{1/p}=\left(\int |g|^p\,d\mu \right)^{1/p}.$$  How could that possibly be the case if $f\neq g$?  I would say I'm done at this point, but clearly I am missing something.  I didn't even use the last equality, i.e. $$\left|\left|\frac{f+g}{2}\right|\right|_p.$$  So what am I missing here?  There must be something I am misunderstanding!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on the equivalence class aspect of $L^{p}$ spaces. I don't think this is that relevant here. How could it be the case that $f\neq g$. What if $p=2$, $X=[0,1]$, $f=x$, and $g=x^{1.5}*\sqrt{4/3}$. Then $\int_{0}^{1} f^2 = 1/3$ and $\int_{0}^{1} g^2 = 4/3\int_{0}^{1} x^3 =   1/3$.

Comment: @Wraith1995 That is a good example.  Thank you for your insight.  Could this equality fail if $p=1$ or $p=\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p-norm $f \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is strictly convex (edit : as a norm on a vector space, not as a function), due to Minkowski inequality.

I will note $\| \cdot \|=\| \cdot \|_p$ for convenience.

If $f \ne \lambda g$ on a set of positive measure for all $\lambda >0$, then for all $t \in (0,1)$ :

$$\|t f +(1-t)g\|<t\|f\| +(1-t)\|g\|.$$

But, having $\|f\|=\|g\|$ being equal to $\left\|\frac{f+g}2 \right\|$ is impossible. Indeed, putting $t = 1/2$ yields :

$$\left\|\frac{f+g}2 \right\|<\frac 1 2 (\| f \| + \|g \|) =\|f\|=\|g\|.$$

Then $f= \lambda g$, but since $\|f\|=|\lambda| \|g\|$ and $\lambda >0$, then $\lambda = 1$.

So we must have $f=g$ a.e. .

Comment: Pardon me if this is a dumb question, but I don't know much about convex functions.  Is the $p$-norm $f\rightarrow ||f||_p$ strictly convex because we are excluding $p=1$ and $p=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.